# Syntax Error : Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to send array parameter to jquery method. I tried to send as a json value. but error occured : unexpected token illegal and it does not show where error is.

How can i send php array value to jquery function as a parameter?

in users.php ->

php part :

```
$objUserStatistics = new UserStatistics;
$user_groups = $objUserStatistics->userGroups($id);
$json_user_groups = json_encode($user_groups);
```

link :

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.show_user_groups('<?=$json_user_groups?>');" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-title="Katıldığı Grup Sayısı"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <?=count($user_groups)?></a></li>
```

in users.js ->

jquery :

```
$.show_user_groups = function(user_groups_val) {
        var user_groups = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < user_groups_val.length; i++) {
            user_groups += '<img src="'+user_groups_val.img_path+'" /> <h5>'+user_groups_val.name+'</h5>';
        }
        $("#myModalLabel").html("Katıldığı Gruplar");
        $(".modal-body").html(user_groups);
        $("#popup_link").trigger("click");
    }
```

how it (link) look like in browser's source code :

[image]

Comment: You might want to use Ajax for sending json between PHP en JS (jQuery).

Comment: You *are* sending the array to the function as an argument. I'd get rid of all of the online JS just to tighten things up though.

Comment: I think you need [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Try this `user_groups_val = JSON.parse(user_groups_val)` before looping through it.

Comment: @Dees040 okay, i call in jquery method using ajax and it works but i am curious about can send a array as a parameter to jquery function ? is it possible ?

Comment: @LeventTulun try JSON.parse() as mentiond above by Jay.